# If the image is changed with a size suffix, then the default link goes to full image

Tags: feature-request, images

I wanted people to zoom into the [images I have in this post](https://superuser.com/q/1237660/47507) so I manually edited the links to allow that click-to-zoom effect.

I'm asking for some kind of shortcut (GUI or javascript hotkey) that will edit the links as I have done in that attached post. (remove the trailing "m" indicator)

Comment: Closely related: [Images should be automatically rescaled and the full size linked or put into a lightbox](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/189343)

Comment: Thanks for the migration. I should have filed it in the correct site.

Comment: This looks like something somebody could write a userscript for.